# Cannot purge Varnish cache from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, request, varnish, purge

I have 'Varnish HTTP Purge' plugin installed in Wordpress. When I'm updating a post, the purge request sent from this plugin is rejected by Varnish, so the post is still read from cache. If I run a curl command the result is the following:

`curl -X PURGE "example.com"`

`Error 405 This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests.`

In my default.vcl file I have:

```
acl purge {
"localhost";
"127.0.0.1";
"::1"; 
}

sub vcl_recv {

 if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
    return(synth(405, "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
    }

    return (purge);
    } 
...
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you are calling purge from localhost?

Comment: Yes, Wordpress is installed on localhost and the purge request comes from that plugin installed in Wordpress. Every purge request sent from the plugin is received by Varnish with the public IP address of the server, so either I leave the configuration as above and cannot update posts in Wordpress, or add the server's public IP address in the 'acl' list but then I have to change it manually whenever that address changes, because it happens it's a dynamic IP address.